# What Is Preventing My Header Image Loading

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

I have been unable to see my header image for a while. I have tried to have separate headers for mobile and non mobile devices. I was using this code (I have now put it in comments using /**/).

```
    /* @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .custom-header { background: url("https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg") no-repeat; width: 100%;
            background-size:contain;
    }


}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
 .custom-header { background: url("https://i1.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg") no-repeat; 
        width: 100% ;
                        background-size:contain;


    }
} */
```

I tried reverting back to the easier way of just doing Customising -> Header Image and choosing a header that way. That is not working anymore either.

It looks as if there is a problem with my Bootstrap code, I am very unfamiliar with Bootstrap but was advised to use it.

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com

When the device width is greater than 601px I want the following to happen

- I don't want there to ever be any space between the menu and the
  custom header
- I don't want there to ever be any space above the
  customer header
- I don't want H1, the plugins or any other content on the page to ever overlap the customer header
- I don't want there to ever be any white space to the left or right of the customer header
- I want to always be able to see the whole text 'Ross The Explorer', I
  don't want the last R to ever be removed

In header.php I had

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</head>
```

I tried removing the following code to see if that would make a difference but my header still did not load.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Comment: Worth noting, you should use wp_enqueue for scripts and styles rather than tags in your header.php file

Answer (score 1):

I would post this as a comment but I can't post comments yet.

The reason why you can't see your image is because you set it to be the background of a `div` instead of it being an actual html object.

In order to see the background of that `div`, it needs to have a defined `height`.

Your `.custom-header` `div` has a specified `width` of `1500px` but no specified `height` and that's why you cannot see it.

There are many ways to fix this but since you are specific about your header I recommend just adding the header as an image by itself

```
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
```

**This doesn't address all the issues** but then again, I only intended this as a comment.

---

**Update:**

In order to add media queries to control the header you can add classes to the `img` tags. You can then use the class - .header-image in my example - selector in CSS to add your media queries.

See the code below:

```css
.header-image {
//** CSS for devices BIGGER than 660px goes here **/
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .header-image {
        //** CSS for devices SMALLER than 660px goes here **/
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="header-image" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you, now my issue is figuring out how to incorporate a media query into header.php. I talk about this problem here -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44552136/incorporating-a-media-query-into-header-php

Comment: You can add classes to the img tags to achieve that. Check the update above

Answer (score 1):

I have now sorted this problem. Thank you for peoples help

I have two header images, one for mobile devices. I have code relating to the header images in header.php and Additional CSS.

In header.php the code is

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>


<img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">


<img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
```

In additional CSS the code is

```
@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
    .mobile-header-img {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .header-img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

My issue now is getting the header to stretch across the whole page. You can read about that issue here [Increasing The Width Of Your Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605554/increasing-the-width-of-your-header).