# Incorporating A Media Query Into header.php

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, header

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com.

I want to have a separate customer header when the site loads on mobile devices, so below 600px and above 601px.

I have attempted to change my header.php code to accomplish this but nothing I have tried has sorted the problem.

Here is my header.php code

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Penscratch
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( 'A|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>



</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>


<img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">


 <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">






<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'jetpack_the_site_logo' ) ) jetpack_the_site_logo(); ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'penscratch' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

            </a>
        <?php endif;  // End header image check. ?>
```

These are the two key lines

```
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">


 <img src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">
```

Comment: You should use CSS media queries to do this and they would be general to your site addressing elements in your mark up.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Where are your media queries that aren't working?

Comment: Add a class to the things you want to show/hide on desktop/mobile, like `.mobile` and `.desktop`, then use `.mobile { display: none; } @media (max-width: 600px) { .desktop { display: none; } .mobile { display: block; } }`?

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael Coker noted above in the comments

add a CSS class to the 'img' tag for mobile displays

You can then use the class selector - `.mobile-header-img` in my example below -  To hide the mobile header if the screen is bigger than 660px

Then do the opposite for the other image to hide the large image from small displays

See the code below:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 660px) {
    .mobile-header-img {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .header-img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">


<img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to have one container element (such as a `<div>`) to hold the header image. Use CSS to assign the `background` property of this element to one of the images. You can then use media queries in the CSS to adjust the `background` property (image) as necessary.